# How to create your own loss function for tf.keras that uses additional parameter?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, loss-function

**My need:**

I would like to modify my loss function in Neural Network by adding sample weights. (I am aware that [.fit method](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) has `sample_weight` parameter).

My idea was to create additional input to my Neural Network with precomputed weights for each train data row like this:

```
# Generating mock data
train_X = np.random.randn(100, 5)
train_Y = np.random.randn(100, 1)
train_sample_weights = np.random.randn(*train_Y.shape)

# Designing loss function that uses my pre-computed weights
def example_loss(y_true, y_pred, sample_weights_):
    return K.mean(K.sqrt(K.sum(K.pow(y_pred - y_true, 2), axis=-1)), axis=0) * sample_weights_

# Two inputs for neural network, one for data, one for weights
input_tensor = Input(shape=(train_X.shape[1],))
weights_tensor = Input(shape=(train_sample_weights.shape[1],))

# Model uses only 'input_tensor'
x = Dense(100, activation="relu")(input_tensor)
out = Dense(1)(x)

# The 'weight_tensor' is inserted into example_loss() functon
loss_function = partial(example_loss, sample_weights_=weights_tensor)

# Model takes as an input both data and weights
model = Model([input_tensor, weights_tensor], out)
model.compile("Adam", loss_function)
model.fit(x=[train_X, train_sample_weights], y=train_Y, epochs=10)
```

**My problem:**

Following code **works** when I use Keras 2.2.4 imports to run it:

```
import numpy as np
from functools import partial

import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
```

Following code **crashes** when I use tf.keras 2.2.4-tf imports to run it:

```
import numpy as np
from functools import partial

import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
```

With the following error:

> TypeError: example_loss() got an unexpected keyword argument
>   'sample_weight'

**My questions:**

1. Why this happens?
2. How could I rewrite the code so such architecture could also work on 2.2.4-tf?
3. Proposition that works on both Keras/tf.keras frameworks is also an acceptable answer for me.

---

Error is easy to reproduce. Just need to copy the code and run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define your loss like that in order to pass new parameters to it :

```
def custom_loss(sample_weights_):

    def example_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return K.mean(K.sqrt(K.sum(K.pow(y_pred - y_true, 2), axis=-1)), axis=0) * sample_weights_

    return example_loss
```

and call it like that :

```
model.compile("Adam", custom_loss(weights_tensor))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your loss like this:

```
# Designing loss function that uses my pre-computed weights
def example_loss(sample_weights_):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return K.mean(K.sqrt(K.sum(K.pow(y_pred - y_true, 2), axis=-1)), axis=0) * sample_weights_
```

As you see, here we have a function that takes the sample weights, and returns another function (the actual loss) that has the sample weights embedded into it. You can use it as:

```
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=example_loss(weights_tensor))
```